# how to display images by using db response like lazylist concept?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, imagesource

i am new developer in android application.i am working on display the images from .net db services.i am communicating with .net web services by using SoapObject class.when i send the request for get the images to db then it is returning encoded strings.i am storing those string in an string array.In Lazy load concept they have stored urls into a string array they are passing that array into LazyAdapter class.instead of url string array i am passing response string array as follows

**Request:**

```
 String photoXml="<spGetUserPhoto><UserID>148</UserID></spGetUserPhoto>";
```

**Response:**

```
  String response=new ParseXMLString().getUserPhotos(newGeneric().photInfo(photoXml));
  String[] photos=new String[response.size()];
  for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++)
  {
      photos[i]=photoResponse;

   }  

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, photos);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**LazyAdapter.java**
i have written getView method in this class as follows

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;


    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);

     TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);;
     ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);

     text.setText(messages[position]);
     try {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vi;

}
```

From the above code i am viewing images when the response has completed.before view the image i am getting blank screen but not default image.

How to display default image untill completion of response?

plzzz any body help me

Comment: First of all image data is binary not String...

Comment: @ingsaurabh  i am converting the enitire string array in Display image class as follows : byte[] imgArry= Base64.decode(photos);   
     
     Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArry,0,imgArry.length);

Comment: before you download image using `imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);` you should set the default image to the `ImageView`. This needs to be done because the convertview is actually the old the view which being re-used and which already has the previously downloaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to use image.setTag(data[position])
2. In the xml of item1.xml you need to give